# Are non-software-related questions about open licenses on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are non-software-related questions about open licenses on-topic or off-topic?

[Example](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/88926/31):

> If I use a [CC-BY background music track](http://beta.ccmixter.org/licenses) in my video on YouTube, is it enough to give credits to the musicians in the video description or must credits be shown in the video?

https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic doesn't seem to specify it, but the name of the SE may imply it's off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Anecdotally, questions about Open Hardware and Creative Commons licenses tend to be well-received here as well. As of now, there are [about 150 upvoted questions on Creative Commons](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcreative-commons%5D+is%3Aquestion+score%3A1).

Your question would have been a very good fit here, and I was slightly confused why you preferred to post it on Law.SE.